# Definining user libraries in Eclipse as part of a project and not a workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I saw that in `Eclipse` I can define **User Libraries** - to make setting the classpath easier (and probably for other reasons as well).

The problem is, that these libraries are only available in the workspace, and if I want other people using the same project to use them - I need to **export** my user library and they need to **import** it.

Is there any functionality like this on the project level? I basically need to have a '**classpath group**' - can it be done?

If not, is there an automatic way to auto import the user library to the workspace when importing the project?

I'm using `Eclipse 3.6`.

Comment: :) We are in transition to Maven, but this project has not reached it yet ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JDT has the 2 concepts, user libraries and classpath variables.  In the classpath variable, you can add jars to your project.  Other team members have to fill in the variables in their workspace so their classpath is complete.  This is useful when external jars might be in different locations on each team members local file system.

The USER_LIBRARY is a container for adding a logical group of local jars all at once.  For example, the JRE_LIB container represents a number of local jars.  But as you've seen, it points to a local set of jars meant to be used in multiple projects (as the JRE is added to multiple projects).

Aside from export/import (which you're already doing), I don't believe you can check CLASS_LIBRARIES into a project's SCM.  If there was, the preference page would have a "Configure Project specific settings" link at the top.

Your best bet is to simply add the jars to the project, so they'll be included in the SCM.  If they can be in different locations depending on the rest of your team, then use a classpath variable so it can be set in each workspace.  That's the least amount of hassle as far as team members checking out the project and being ready to go.

Comment: Thanks, so it seems from your answer that the answer to my question is: "No". 
My problem is I just want to make things simpler and easier. We are using `SoapUI` for tests, it has a dependency list of around 30 jars - I wanted to combine them all in one list so it is easy to add/remove them from the classpath. They are all in the source control - but I have no easy way of distributing this configuration to the rest of the developers. For now I'll prefer to keep them all in the common classpath.

Comment: For newbie reference JDT == Eclipse Java development tools: http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/

Answer (score 2):

The best way IMO is to **use m2eclipse - Maven plugin for eclipse**. In Maven all the dependencies are defined in pom.xml and downloaded automatically as needed. This means that the only thing you share with your team is pom.xml - your project definition.

There is a lot more advantages when using m2eclipse vs standard eclipse approch. More information is at http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/

Answer (score 0):

The way I have used user libraries is for something like Ant. Define a user library "ant" for all the jars in ANT_HOME/lib. If including this in your Eclipse .classpath and then sharing with other users, they will get a build problem report until they create that "ant" user library themselves. It's useful, but you need to share knowledge on how to create the library. If you're using it for simple cases like above, then instructions for adding the right jars to the library are straightforward.

Another approach I've used is to build classpaths pointing into a folder (or folders) defined as a variable in Eclipse. See `File -> New Folder -> Advanced -> Link to folder in the file system -> Variables`. This lets you setup (again at workspace level) variable references to one or more folders. You can then build your Eclipse classpath/s with reference to the folder/s.

So say in your development environment, everyone needs to have a directory called "thirdparty" containing all the external jars dependencies (probably in hierarchy within that dir: thirdparty/apache; thirdparty/sun; ...). You define "thirdparty" as a variable pointing to wherever that dir is on your current system, you create a folder in your project/s using the variable. You can then setup (and share) classpath using paths into that folder.

It's similar to User Library and with similar limitations. The limitation is that the other users you share your project with must create variable folder/s as you have. But it's more flexible in that they don't have to add the jars explicitly as they do with a library; rather, your classpath/s in Eclipse point into the folder, as required for each project.

Note that although the folder variable is defined at workspace level, it can be reused in multiple projects, each of which builds their classpaths (.classpath files) with different references into the folder).

This is maybe something easier to show than to describe with words, but I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm actually trying to avoid a situation where I need to ask my team members to perform a manual action. The purpose of this is to make it easier, currently I just add all the jars in the `.classpath`, just wanted to group them under one logical name to make it simpler to manage